# The Idea of a slack or dummy variable in an optimization problem

Tags: inequality, optimization, linear-programming

Consider the following maximization problem:
$$\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}}f(x) \\
s.t.\quad g(x)\leq r$$

Here, I found that introducing a slack or dummy variable can convert the inequality constraint into an equality constraint:
$$\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}}f(x) \\
s.t.\quad g(x)+s= r$$
where $s$ is the slack variable.

I want to know the underlying idea of this technique but I cannot find a good reference for that.

How does this technique work?

Comment: Learn linear programming. That is where the concept is introduced.

Comment: @JohnDouma I found that the inequality and equality constraints with non-negative slack variables are equivalent. Thus, I think, the reason why the slack variable technique works is just that we are imposing the same constraint. Is it correct?

Comment: To ensure that the two formulations are equivalent you need to add the condition $s \geq 0$, since a negative value for $s$ would allow values of $g(x)$ greater than $r$.

Comment: @david_sap Thank you. I totally understood!

Comment: The constraints place the feasible solutions into half spaces. When we set a slack variable to zero (by pivoting) we are placing our point on the boundary. By setting multiple slack variables to zero we are checking our solutions at the vertices of a polyhedron. Using negative values as opposed to positive values ensures we are still within the appropriate half space, regardless of whether we are seeking the maximum or the minimum.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thank you. Then, my last question is that I think, the slack variable should be a function of $x$ since $s=r-g(x)$ but, when we partially differentiate the lagrange function including the slack variable with respect to $x$, we consider the slack variable as a constant. How can this be sensible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have never seen slack variables used with Lagrange multipliers; I have only seen them used with linear programming. You may be working with a more advanced technique that I haven't seen.

Comment: @JohnDouma I see, your comments are very helpful. Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: @MinChulPark The slack variable $s$ is not a function of $x$. You should think of $s$ as a new variable on its own, which is independent from $x$. Writing $s = r - g(x)$ only means that you are trying to enforce this equality (which is possible if there is a feasible solution to your problem), not that you are defining $s$ as $r - g(x)$. You can therefore differentiate both with respect to $x$ (keeping $s$ constant) or with respect to $s$ (with $x$ constant). You should think of the introduction of the slack variable as adding one additional dimension to your problem.